# A question of size

Tags: riddle, wordplay

There is an object on earth that behaves in a curious manner.

> It gets bigger the more you take out of it and smaller the more you put into it.

**What is it?**

Comment: Size *does* matter!

Comment: Nice wordplay !

Comment: This is a well known puzzle, and it is very low quality anyway

Comment: I know a variation of this riddle: "It doesn't weight anything, but it's able to let a ship sink"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a

> hole.
>
>  As you remove material (like dirt for example) the hole gets larger; as you add material, it gets smaller.

Comment: >! yeah, that was quick! @tmpearce. what has holes but still holds water?

Comment: @NONAMEBRAND A sponge.

Comment: Indeed, you've played knifey spoon before! @rand al'thor

Answer (score 3):

Is it

> Debt?
>  The more money you take out of an account that is in debt, the more you will owe. If you owe more money, than the debt is larger. Likewise, if you put more money into the account in debt, the smaller the debt will be.